# unable to get object property of oleobject class

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to migrate an excel project from office 2003 to office 2010, and I keep hitting errors, trying to resolve them I'm not at an error that reads:

```
Unable to get Object Property of OleObjects Class
```

The line that generates this error is at `SrcContainer = pTitleSheet.OLEObjects(1)` where pTitleSheet is a microsoft excel object with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub MasterTitleBox_BeforeContextMenu(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal Menu As OWC11.ByRef, ByVal Cancel As OWC11.ByRef)
  'MsgBox CStr(x) + " " + CStr(y)
  Cancel = True

End Sub
```

I don't know how to debug the error or find out why it cant find an OLEObject as the code ran in Office 2003.

I furthermore have the problem, that I can't see the object that I have posted code for above, meaning that I have no option to "view object" see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to show at little more code: at least include your variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are no OLEObjects on the sheet.  Try looking at `pTitleSheet.OLEObjects.count` before this

```
line SrcContainer = pTitleSheet.OLEObjects(1)
```

They could have been changed from ActiveX controls to form controls on the sheet.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15BA7E28-8D7F-42AB-9470-FFB9AB94E7C2#bmcontrols_on_the_forms_toolbar