# VBA Commands incompatible between Excel 2010 and 2013 (OLEObject)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro file shared across some users, all with Excel 2010 version. We are trying to have it run with some people with Excel 2013, but the macro seems to block everytime we need to call some OLEObjects (mainly buttons and checkboxes) with the following error message:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class
```

These are three code samples that trigger the error:

1:

```
If Not (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main page").OLEObjects("CheckBox2").Object.Value) Then
```

2:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main page").OLEObjects("OptionButton3").Object.Value Then
```

3:

```
variableName = mPage.OLEObjects("OptionButton5").Object.Value
```

I'm not an expert in VBA but I wrote part of the macro myself, so I may be able to modify the macro if the button Objects just need to be accessed in a different way in the newest versions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777481/unable-to-get-object-property-of-oleobject-class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367215/unable-to-get-the-object-property-of-the-oleobject-class-excel-interop

Comment: Are you sure that there really are OLEObjects in your migrated workbook? Can you try something like `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count`? What does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Shapes object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes). Maybe you have shapes and no OLEObjects.

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main page").Shapes("Check Box 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value
```

You can test it with

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main page").Shapes.Count
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main page").OLEObjects.Count
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but I'm having a hard time finding the time to fix this. Interestingly, it seems that those objects are not considered as OLEObjects, but neither as Shapes.

However, newly created checkboxes / radio buttons / else are recognised as shapes. Since it's only 10 buttons, I will "fix" this by removing the old "broken" OLEObjects and adding the new "Shapes", then fix the references in code. Probably not the best way, but seems the easiest.

Thanks!